# Create shared folder accessible from domain with C#

Tags: c#, deployment-project

I'm doing a Deployment Project in VS2008, and at the end of the installation flow I need to create a shared folder with Full Control permissions to Everyone on the local machine accessible from a company domain.
I succeeded to create the shared folder, but Everyone has read access.
Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Valeriu

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the `ManagementClass` to [create a shared folder](http://www.sarampalis.org/articles/dotnet/dotnet0002.shtml).

Setting the Access field of your `ManagementBaseObject` should give full control to everyone:

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_share");
ManagementBaseObject inParams = mc.GetMethodParameters("Create");
inParams["Description"] = "Shared Folder";
// ... whathever ...
inParams["Access"] = null; // <-- should give full control access to everyone
```

If the above doesn't work you might wanna try explicitly setting the security level with smt like the following:

```
    public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings.  
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                         Rights,
                                                         ControlType));
        // Set the new access settings. 
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
    }
```

If none of the above helps, then I'd suggest you post your code.

Comment: The code is nothing special. The installer just creates a directory on the local machine and tries to share it. I tried your code also, but still doesn't work.
The 
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_share");
code, indeed, shares the directory over the domain, but only with Read access to Everyone.
The 
AddDirectorySecurity
method does nothing.

Comment: Would this be because the Installer is running with the System user and that doesn't have enough permissions?

Comment: I also think that inParams["Access"] = null; gives access to Everyone, but read-only